# PutItem to DynamoDB success, but there is no data on DynomoDB

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I created a DynomoDB with partition key of PK type string:

If I set `PK` as int I will have this error

> One or more parameter values were invalid: Type mismatch for key PK
> expected: S actual: N

(I suppose I connect to dynamoDB success).

But when I change my PK to int, the code works normal but there is no data in DynamoDB

```
type Item struct {
    PK     int
    Title  string
    Plot   string
    Rating float64
}

func main() {

    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials("AKIA6HAR6GXXXXXXX", "dr/ErExNkV9Z8dABtXXXXXXXXX", ""),
        Region:      aws.String("ap-southeast-1")},
    )
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    svc := dynamodb.New(sess)
    item := Item{
        PK:     123,
        Title:  "The Big New Movie",
        Plot:   "Nothing happens at all.",
        Rating: 0.0,
    }
    av, err := dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(item)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Got error marshalling new movie item: %s", err)
    }
    tableName := "t_user"
    input := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
        Item:      av,
        TableName: aws.String(tableName),
    }

    output, err := svc.PutItem(input)
}
```

`err` from the line `output, err := svc.PutItem(input)`

Comment: How do you confirm there is no data?

Comment: You said "err from the line ..." - but then didn't complete this sentence... Was there an error? What was it?

Comment: @NadavHar'El err mentioned above is at that line